# Using an isometry to convert a conic section to standard form

Tags: matrices, conic-sections, isometry

> Find the isometry that takes the conic section
>
> $\qquad 3x^2-4xy+3y^2+\sqrt2 x+\sqrt2 y = 0 \quad (*)$
>
> to standard form.
>
> **Solution**. First, $3x^2-4xy+3y^2=\pmatrix{x & y}A \pmatrix{x \\ y}$, where $A =\pmatrix{3 & -2 \\ -2 & 2}$.
>
> $A$ has eigenvalues $1,5$ and corresponding eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1 \\ 1},\pmatrix{1 \\ -1}$.
>
> Let $\pmatrix{x \\ y}=Q\pmatrix{X \\ Y}$, where $Q =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1}$. Then, the LHS of $(*)$ becomes
>
> $3x^2-4xy+3y^2+\sqrt2 x+\sqrt2 y$
>
> $=\pmatrix{X & Y}Q^TAQ \pmatrix{X \\ Y} + 2X$
>
> $=X^2+5Y^2+2X$
>
> ...

I don't quite understand the particular choice of $Q =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1}$.

From the statement $\pmatrix{x \\ y}=Q\pmatrix{X \\ Y}$,  $Q$ could be any $2\times 2$ matrix whose image is a superset of the conic section (?).

It seems that we specifically choose $Q$ to be orthogonal in order for it to be an isometry, and its columns are the eigenvectors of $A$, which makes matrix multiplications easier when $A$ is diagonalised.

Also, the conic's equation is an ellipse slanted at a $45$-degree angle to the $x$-axis, and I noticed that the columns of $Q$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb 
 R^2$ rotated by exactly that angle. But I'm not sure if it's some sort of rotation or just a coincedence.

What exactly is this method doing to the conic section?

Would some other orthogonal (or even non-orthogonal, if we didn't require an isometry) choice of $Q$ also work here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Comment: Notice that $Q$ is built up of the eigenvectors of $A$ and scaled to have determinant $-1$.